# Does Lambda completely demolish the usage the anonymous inner class from java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, anonymous-class

I saw many examples how to convert anonymous inner classes to simple lambda expressions .

i understand technical differences between both of them .

But i just want to know when to when ?

what is the business usecase scenario to use Anonymous Inner class after introduction of lambdas ?

Does Lambda completely demolish the usage the anonymous inner class from java 8 ?

Comment: lambda does not work if the anonymous class has more than one method.

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas can only be used in place of `SAM` (Single Abstract Method) classes. Sometimes these abstract classes are annotated with [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) to emphasise the fact that they can be replaced by a lambda expression.

The answer to your question is **No**. Anonymous classes still have their usage, the lambda syntax is just there to simplify the creation of classes that only contain a single abstract method such as [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), [etc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html),

Answer (score 3):

imagine this case

```
interface Anon {
   void m1();
   void m2();
}
```

and a method that takes this interface

```
void useAnon(Anon a);
```

you will not be able to use lambda for this case.

```
useAnon( new Anon(){
   @Override void m1(){System.out.println("use m1");};
   @Override void m2(){System.out.println("use m2");};

});
```